# Помогите дописать алгоритм на python

Tags: python

Пытался реализовать этот алгоритм[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Застрял на том, что выдаёт ошибку при удалении из `Z` всех вершин, смежных с `x`

```py
     def clique(graph):
        if not any((N, D)):
            print('Clique found: ' + str(S))
        elif N:
            x = N[0]
            View(x, graph)
            Z.remove(x)
            Adj_list = Adj(x, X)
            for i in range(len(Adj_list)): 
                Z.remove(Adj_list[i]) ! тут выдаёт ошибку
            while Z:
                v = Z[0]
                View(v, graph)
                Z.remove(v)

    def View(v, graph):
        N.remove(v)
        S.append(v)
        clique(graph)
        S.remove(v)
        D.append(v)

    def Adj(v, X): 
        return [i for i, n_v in enumerate(X[v]) if n_v]

    graph = [[0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]



    X = []
    for i in range(len(graph)):
        X.append(i)

    S = []
    N = X.copy()
    D = []
    Z = X.copy()
    clique(graph)
```

Comment: а к чему относится последняя инструкция "global?"

Comment: @finally честно говоря я не силён в питоне просто хотел чтоб эти переменные были в глобальной области

Comment: в том то и дело, что если это не кусок, а цельный код, то эти переменные и так в глобальной области)

Comment: ну и второе - когда вы пишите 'global' вы как бы переобъявляете эти переменные но уже в локальной области, т.к если бы вы просто выводили их, функция бы их в "глобал" нашла, а если хотели бы изменить, она бы выдала ошибку, т.к они объявлены не в этом пространстве имен.. по этому вы не делаете их глобальными, а наоборот - "забираете" их из глобала

Comment: @finally исправил, пасиб

Comment: @Netras `X[v]` - число, к нему не может быть применена функция `enumerate()`. Скажите, что должна принимать и что должна возвращать функция `Adj()` (её логику работы), и я смогу помочь исправить ошибку.